# Excel IF Statement evaluating Cell in Table and Changing Number

Tags: excel, list

I am looking for help on a project of mine. The project requires me to go through a table in Excel and evaluate one cell in a column then add up numbers from that cell's row into a singular cell. Sorry it sounds confusing but I'll try to type it in Java code.

'''

```
//CellColumn = The cell I am trying to evaluate
//CellMainC = The cell I am trying to compare/evaulate CellColumn to
//CellRow = The cell I am trying to get the number from
//CellMainR = The cell I'm trying to aggregate numbers from CellRow

if(CellColumn=CellMainC)
{
CellMainR + CellRow;
}
else if (CellColumn!=CellMainC)
{
//This is where I get stuck
Continue going down list until CellColumn = CellMainC
}
else
{
return;
}
```

'''

Comment: I've written a quick [Google-sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fsz6peksproucjQuY2XAtFN9iCN4oLytVo_BwkoGYxc/edit?usp=sharing) with the formula on cell G3 and the number you're trying to evaluate on cell F3 and the number you're evaluating it against, on A1; to see if this is the question you're trying to answer...

Comment: you should've pushed him in the right direction. you shouldn't have given him the answer straight away. he won't learn from that :)

Comment: Ah! I'm new to answering questions myself... I really appreciate the help I received when all I did was ask questions, and was eager to help out when i felt I knew the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO,

I assume that you are using the VBA editor?

you should play around with the `ActiveCell` property. and whenever `(CellColumn!=CellMainC)` is true you want the activecell to go down by using the `offset` property

usefull links that explain the activecell and offset property:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activecell
https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/offset.html

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions.